# How to talk about closure of videos, and TV?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I feel that the word **close** is used with something which has lid or doors.

Can I say **close the TV**?
Can I say **close the videos**?

If not, then what is the proper way to talk about them?

Comment: Do you mean "turn off the TV "? close the video is common in working with computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to machines or devices (TV, radio, lights, etc), you use *turn off* as Cardinal told you.

Now *close* is not necessarily used with lid or doors, you can also use it along with prepositions to create a new meaning. Namely, ***close in*** (surround or envelop), ***close on*** (get near to something or someone), ***close up*** (join together) and so on.

Comment: As @Cardinal also pointed out, "Close" is used to stop applications on a computer because you "close" the window in which the application is running.